# Ajax display number of day between two dates (input tag) without submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am making a system that allows the user to input two dates. The system then returns a calculation like how many Mondays there are between the two dates.

[image: Image of the problem]

I am given the initial date and the final date. In the gray input, that is in read only mode I must return the number of days (Monday) between those two dates, all without having to press anything.

I enter the dates and it automatically calculates. I've created a php function that works, I need the hand because I'm not an ajax expert.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be more specific on your question. What you did so far? What exactly do you need help with? What did you attempt so far?

Comment: You mean as soon as the second date is entered it will automatically calculate? Look into keyup or input events, so you can detect when the change occurs to the field. Not sure what you mean by read only mode though?? And also the title of the question appears to bear no relation to the content unless, again, you can clarify?

Comment: When the dates are both entered, the automatic calculation is returned without doing anything else. The output is in a input tag in readonly so the user can't modify it.

Comment: You don't need a read-only input for that necessarily, you can just output it into a div or span, or any other element which is already read only. But otherwise yes you just need to handle the correct events on the date fields

Answer (score -2):

Use setinterval example `setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);`

Comment: So you make an AJAX call every 3 seconds even if no data have been provided in the form ?

Comment: do not you test first if the input is filled then you run the ajax query

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {
     setInterval ( test, 3000 );       });
     function test(){
         var stard=$('#stard').val();
         var end=$('#end').val();
         if(end!=undefined && stard!=undefined){
                // code ajax
         }
   }`